# convert to date with strtotime, the output always empty with special char

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match, preg-match-all

i tried to cut special char in this date, when i try to convert to date with strtotime, the output always empty. but in another date it's work. why ?

data special char :

```
Â  Â 11:44:08 AM 10/24/2012Â  Â 
Â  Â 3:37:43 PM 9/8/2012Â  Â 
Â  Â 13:21:22 09/01/2017Â  Â
Â  Â 0:30:06 13/09/2017Â  Â
Â  Â 0:32:00 13/09/2017Â  Â
```

date example :

```
11:44:08 AM 10/24/2012 
3:37:43 PM 9/8/2012 
13:21:22 09/01/2017 
0:30:06 13/09/2017 
0:32:00 13/09/2017
```

convert to strotime :

```
1351071848
1347111463
1504264882
empty *mean nothing 
empty
```

CODE :

```
$test  = preg_replace("/[^0-9a-zA-Z \/:\-]/", "", $date);
$xtime = strtotime($date);
$result   = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$xtime);
```

Final Result :

```
2012-10-24 11:44:08
2012-09-08 15:37:43
2017-09-01 13:21:22
1970-01-01 01:00:00
1970-01-01 01:00:00
```

Comment: You likely need a global "g" flag on the regular expression: `/[^0-9a-zA-Z \/:\-]/g` to replace all matches, not just the first. This does not seem to be about javascript.

Comment: i tried to add it. still not work

Comment: strtotime function does not work properly with dd/mm/yyyy format. To solve this you can replace "/" with "-". strtotime("0:30:06 13-09-2017") will give you timestamp.

Comment: it's works. but in first row output not convert.

1970-01-01 01:00:00
2012-08-09 15:37:43
2017-01-09 13:21:22
2017-09-13 00:30:06
2017-09-13 00:32:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [these `strtotime` notes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

> Dates in the *m/d/y* or *d-m-y* formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (`/`), then the American *m/d/y* is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (`-`) or a dot (`.`), then the European *d-m-y* format is assumed. If, however, the year is given in a two digit format and the separator is a dash (`-`), the date string is parsed as *y-m-d*.

You may try the following logic that you may extend further if need be:

```
$arr = ['Â  Â 11:44:08 AM 10/24/2012Â  Â','Â  Â 3:37:43 PM 9/8/2012Â  Â ','Â  Â 13:21:22 09/01/2017Â  Â','Â  Â 0:30:06 13/09/2017Â  Â','Â  Â 0:32:00 13/09/2017Â  Â'];
foreach ($arr as $date){
    $test  = preg_replace("~[^0-9a-zA-Z\s/:-]+~u", "", $date);
    $result = $test." => ";
    if (($xtime = strtotime($test)) === false) // European dd/MM/yyyy format?
    { 
        if (($xtime = strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $test))) === false) {
            $result .= "UNKNOWN FORMAT"; // add more logic here if need be
        } else {
            $result .= date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $xtime);
        }
    }
    else { // OK, it is MM/dd/yyyy
        $result .= date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$xtime);
    }
    echo $result."\n";
}
```

Output:

```
11:44:08 AM 10/24/2012   => 2012-10-24 11:44:08
3:37:43 PM 9/8/2012    => 2012-09-08 15:37:43
13:21:22 09/01/2017   => 2017-09-01 13:21:22
0:30:06 13/09/2017   => 2017-09-13 00:30:06
0:32:00 13/09/2017   => 2017-09-13 00:32:00
```